# How can you prevent condensation/damp when you plan to leave a car idle?

Tags: cleaning

My old car tends to develop condensation quite easily.  If you leave your car in a cold climate not ventilated for an extended period of time I guess that is what happens.

If we plan to leave our cars parked up for extended times, what can we do to prevent condensation?  you cannot leave windows open since although it provides ventilation rain may poor in. I'm just wondering if we can remove some part of the car to ventilate the inside etc but without letting rain water or splashes from ground get in or what people may be doing to get around this.

Comment: Should be combined with https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/64103/10976

Answer (score 1):

The condensation comes from too much moisture trapped inside the vehicle, usually from a slight water leak. Do your best to dry out the interior: max the heat whenever you drive and have the windows open whenever possible. To find the leak wipe all the carpeting, including under the dash and seats, with plain writing paper. Check the paper for moisture.

Comment: what is the point opening the window with heaters on, the heat will just escape?  Are you meant to have them closed when heating or a little open?

Comment: Oops, I meant windows open just a bit. The warmed air can pick up humidity, then carry it out the windows.

Comment: Switch the Heater/Air Coditioner to OFF when the car is not in use. If you don't the fresh air vent remains open allowing damp air inside.

Answer (score 1):

Pick up some of the desiccant crystal based dehumidifiers [such as these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pingi-Dehumidifer-Car-Home-Multicolor/dp/B00I3VKBJS?ascsubtag=35899) and pop one on your dashboard and one on the rear parcel shelf.

Keep an eye on them and when "full" just pop them in the microwave for 5-6 minutes and you're good to go again.